# How to add to strong parameter whitelist for gem acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, voting

I have been using the ruby gem 'acts_as_votable' (https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) and have been pleased with its ease of use.

My problem arises from the gem's lack of explicit controller creation. Without the controller (and model, so no fallback to attr_accessible) I am unable to edit the strong parameter whitelist. I therefore can't pass a value to a new column I have added to the votes db.

I've tried creating my own Votes controller, pasting in the 'voter_params' (with my additional param) from the gem's lib/extenders/controller.rb resulting in no success.

If anybody knows how I could add to this parameter whitelist it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using rails 4?

Comment: Yes, Rails 4.1.1 - Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into your `Config > initializers > acts_as_votable.rb`

```
module ActsAsVotable
  ActsAsVotable::Vote.class_eval do
      attr_accessible :votable, :voter, :vote_scope
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. It also requires the 'protected_attributes' gem which I was trying to avoid.

My attempt at a rails 4 strong params version (which also failed) was as follows:
`ActsAsVotable::Vote.class_eval do

 def votable_params(params_object = params[:vote])
     params_object.permit(:vote_registered)
  end

  def voter_params(params_object = params[:vote])
   params_object.permit(:votable_id, :votable_type,
     :voter_id, :voter_type,
     :votable, :voter,
     :vote_flag, :vote_scope, :vote_time)
 end
 
end`